# Facebook ads do not work with expo sdk 33

Tags: react-native, expo, facebook-ads-api

I have upgraded my Expo sdk to the latest one (33.0.0). I have changed all that I need (I changed import of fb ads like this:

`import * as FacebookAds from 'expo-ads-facebook';` and downloaded it).

When I ran this app 2 days ago (I was on sdk 32) all was ok, but now...
I read that all that I need to change so the `fb ads` work was just import and downloading. When I run my app fb ads does not show and it give in console this error:

```
error SyntheticEvent {
  "_dispatchInstances": FiberNode {
    "tag": 5,
    "key": null,
    "type": "ViewManagerAdapter_CTKBannerView",
  },
  "_dispatchListeners": [Function onError],
  "_targetInst": FiberNode {
    "tag": 5,
    "key": null,
    "type": "ViewManagerAdapter_CTKBannerView",
  },
  "bubbles": undefined,
  "cancelable": undefined,
  "currentTarget": 1255,
  "defaultPrevented": undefined,
  "dispatchConfig": Object {
    "registrationName": "onAdError",
  },
  "eventPhase": undefined,
  "isDefaultPrevented": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse],
  "isPropagationStopped": [Function functionThatReturnsFalse],
  "isTrusted": undefined,
  "nativeEvent": Object {
    "errorCode": 1002,
    "errorMessage": "Ad was re-loaded too frequently",
  },
  "target": undefined,
  "timeStamp": 1562671873682,
  "type": undefined,
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
Code:

```html
// page.js
import React from 'react';

import { View } from 'react-native';
import { createStackNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'; // Version can be specified in package.json
import * as FacebookAds from 'expo-ads-facebook';

import AdScreenFacebook from './AdScreenFacebook'

const adsManager = new FacebookAds.NativeAdsManager("2272791379702600_2272795453035526", 10);

class AdScreen extends React.Component {
  render () {
          return (
  <View>
  <AdScreenFacebook adsManager={adsManager} />

  <FacebookAds.BannerAd
      placementId="2272791379702600_2272803043034767"
      type="standard"
      onPress={() => console.log('click')}
      onError={error => console.log('error', error)}
    />
    </View>
          );
      }

 }


  export default createStackNavigator(
    {
      Main: {
        screen: AdScreen,
      },
      AdScreenFacebook: {
        screen: AdScreenFacebook,
      }
    },
    {
      initialRouteName: 'Main',
    }
  );
  
  // AdScreenFacebook.js
  
  import React from 'react';

import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';

import * as FacebookAds from 'expo-ads-facebook';
const { AdTriggerView, AdMediaView, AdIconView } = FacebookAds;


class AdScreenFacebook extends React.Component {
  render () {
          return (
            <View style={{  flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',}}>
            <View style={{ width:500}}>
                   <AdMediaView style={{ width: 160, height: 90 }}/>
                   <View style={{flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                   <AdIconView style={{ width: 50, height: 50 }}/>
                   <AdTriggerView>
                     <Text>{this.props.nativeAd.bodyText}</Text>
                       <Text>{this.props.nativeAd.callToActionText}</Text>
                   </AdTriggerView>
                 </View>
                  </View>
                    </View>
    );
      }

 }


export default FacebookAds.withNativeAd(AdScreenFacebook);
```

Answer (score 0):

Upgrading the FB SDK is an [open issue](https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/4421) right now.

Currently, it is confirmed that the Expo build is not being implemented under conditions that do not separate, resulting in errors.

If you want to use it now, you run `expo eject` **(use Expokit)**